# Dimension mismatch while building LSTM RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build multilayer, multiclass, multilabel LSTM in Tensorflow. I have been trying to bend [this](https://github.com/aqibsaeed/Multilabel-timeseries-classification-with-LSTM/blob/master/RNN%20-%20Multilabel.ipynb) tutorial to my data.

However, I am getting an error that says I have dimension mismatch when building RNN.

**ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1000 and 923 for 'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,1000], [923,2000].**

I cannot pinpoint which variable is incorrect in building architecture:

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.0, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def lstm(x, weight, bias, n_steps, n_classes):

    cell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(cfg.n_hidden_cells_in_layer, state_is_tuple=True)
    multi_layer_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * 2)

    # FIXME : ERROR binding x to LSTM as it is
    output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    # FIXME : ERROR

    output_flattened = tf.reshape(output, [-1, cfg.n_hidden_cells_in_layer])
    output_logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(output_flattened, weight), bias)

    output_all = tf.nn.sigmoid(output_logits)
    output_reshaped = tf.reshape(output_all, [-1, n_steps, n_classes])

    # ??? switch batch size with sequence size. ???
    # then gather last time step values
    output_last = tf.gather(tf.transpose(output_reshaped, [1, 0, 2]), n_steps - 1)


    return output_last, output_all
```

**These are my placeholders, loss function and all that jazz:**

```
x_test, y_test = load_multiple_vector_files(test_filepaths)
x_valid, y_valid = load_multiple_vector_files(valid_filepaths)

n_input, n_steps, n_classes = get_input_target_lengths(check_print=False)


# FIXME n_input should be the problem
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
y_steps = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

weight = weight_variable([cfg.n_hidden_layers, n_classes])
bias = bias_variable([n_classes])
y_last, y_all = lstm(x, weight, bias, n_steps, n_classes)

#all_steps_cost=tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_mean((y_steps * tf.log(y_all))+(1 - y_steps) * tf.log(1 - y_all),reduction_indices=1))
all_steps_cost = -tf.reduce_mean((y_steps * tf.log(y_all)) + (1 - y_steps) * tf.log(1 - y_all))
last_step_cost = -tf.reduce_mean((y * tf.log(y_last)) + ((1 - y) * tf.log(1 - y_last)))
loss_function = (cfg.alpha * all_steps_cost) + ((1 - cfg.alpha) * last_step_cost)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=cfg.learning_rate).minimize(loss_function)
```

I am pretty sure it is my **X placeholder** that is causing the problem, resulting in layers and their matrices dimensions not matching. The constant which the linked example is using is rather tough to see what it actually stands for.

Can anyone help me out here? :)

**UPDATE:**
I have made an "educated guess" on the mismatching dimensions.
One is 2*hidden_width, so hidden getting new input + its old recurrent input. The mismatching dimension, however, is **input_width + hidden_width**, like it was trying to set recurrency for width of hidden layer to the input layer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I am incorrectly setting the weight variable, using the constant for n_hidden_layers(number of hidden layers) instead of n_hidden_cells_in_layer(number of layers).